# C# if statement interpretation

Tags: c#, logic

I'm confused about a simple thing. In my opinion the result of line 4 must be the same as the one of line 6. Can somebody explain what the optimizer is doing on line 5.

I expected `b` to be decremented and incremented on each line. So the value of `b` must have 2 at the begin of interpretation of the line. So the result should have been the same for line 4 and 6.

```
1. int a = 1;
2. int b = 2;
3. 
4. Console.WriteLine(a == --b && a == b++); // expected: true, real: true
5. Console.WriteLine(a == --b || a == b++); // expected: true, real: true 
6. Console.WriteLine(a == --b && a == b++); // expected: true, real: false
```

Comment: Please explain **why** you think the output of 4 and 6 should be the same. (hint, `b` does not have the same value at the start of those two statements, contrary to what you intended)

Comment: b is decremeted and incremented on each line. so the start value of b must have 2 at the begin of interpretation of the line. So the result must be the same for line 4 and 6.

Comment: Good, now that you've described what you expected, check the answers below for an explanation of why that doesn't happen.

Comment: `--` and `++` modify the value of b. But Line 5 only one of the expression is evaluated because it's an  OR. execution be like :"First part is right so why test the second".

Comment: i know that this was probably only an academic example to understand c#. But you see the result. It is hard to read. never mix incrementations with boolean expressions like that in real code.

Comment: Actually, while I agree with not mixing increment or decrement operators into other expressions, the issue here is really with side-effects in expressions used in combination with short-circuiting boolean operators.

Comment: Is there an interpretation direction rule?

Comment: The `a || b` expression is evaluated left to right, but `||` is a short-circuiting boolean operator, in the sense that if the final result is obtained after just evaluating `a`, then `b` will not be evaluated at all. This is why you can do `if (a == null || a.Value == null)`, if `||` where to evaluate both, always, then this would crash if `a == null` would be true, because the other subexpression would produce a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was quick. :)

Comment: As a little addition you can use `if (a == --b | a == b++)` the `|` operator will never short circuit and always evaluate both sides resulting in your desired behaviour

Answer (score 4):

In line 4, `b` is decremented and incremented, leaving 2.

In line 5, `b` is decremented, then because `a == --b` is `true`, the expression short-circuits and `b` is not incremented, leaving 1.

In line 6 `a == --b` is now `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The || operator applies the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
So, for the || operator, if the first term of the expression is true there is no need to evaluate (execute) the second term.

The effect of this logic on your code is that the second part of the expression in line 5 is not executed and the variable b remains at 1 after the decrement.
This leads to the line 6 giving false as result

Answer (score 1):

When the 4. and 5. line is called it also changes the value of the variable:

a is 1 and b is 2

```
a == --b && a == b++ = true
```

a is 1 and b is 2

```
a == --b && a == b++ = true
```

a is 1 and b is 1 because second part of the above statement did not run. If first part of the or (||) operator is true, second part will not be executed.

```
a == --b && a == b++ = false
```

a is not equal to 0 (1 - 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. int a = 1;
2. int b = 2;
3. 
4. Console.WriteLine(a == --b && a == b++); // expected: true, real: true
5. Console.WriteLine(a == --b || a == b++); // expected: true, real: true 
6. Console.WriteLine(a == --b && a == b++); // expected: true, real: false
```

becomes

```
1. int a = 1;
2. int b = 2;
3.

   // now: a = 1, b = 2
   // b is decremented to 1, expressions are evaluated. b is incremented to 2,
4. Console.WriteLine(1 == 1 && 1 == 1); 

   // now: a = 1, b = 2
   // b is decremented to 1, first expression is evaluated to true, 
   // that causes the second expression to be short circuited. It doesnt 
   // matter whether it is true or false, the whole expression will be true anyway.
   // So the second expression will not be executed.
5. Console.WriteLine(1 == 1);   

   // now: a = 1, b = 1
   // b is decremented to 0, expressions are evaluated, b is incremented to 1
6. Console.WriteLine(1 == 0 && 1 == 0);
```